# ¿Cómo direccionar a otro archivo del mismo directorio en diferentes carpetas con PHP?

Tags: php

Dentro de una carpeta, tengo el sistema de administración, llamada `admin` y en el directorio local del dominio, es decir donde están todos los archivos `index.php` entre más, la carpeta indicada.

Para acceder al admin, debe iniciar sesión en el directorio local `example.com/login.php` para ser direccionada a `example.com/admin/index.php`.

Pero si no ha iniciado sesión, y accede directamente a `example.com/admin/index.php`, debe ser direccionado a `example.com/login.php`

e intentado lo siguiente:

```
header("Location: login.php");
```

Pero el resultado no es el esperado me direcciona a:

`example.com/admin/login.php`

en vez de `example.com/login.php`

¿Cómo puedo redirrecionar a la ruta correcta usando `header()` de `PHP`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes redireccionar, agregando el dominio completo con el archivo deseado de la siguiente manera:

```
header('Location: http://example/login.php');
```

O a la vez de la siguiente forma:

```
header("Location: ../login.php");
```

Comment: Ha dado resultados, por qué no lo pensé antes, era tan sencillo y fácil... Gracias.